# How do I cache configure settings for static libraries that are built using Ant scripts and SCONS?

Tags: caching, ant, performance, scons

Currently, we build a group of static libraries prior to building our app. The issue is that for each library there is some variation of the ./configure, make , test sequence. I would like to be able to cache the results of the configure step to speed up the build, since it is common to build on the same platform multiple times. We are thinking about wrapping each step in the build process in an SCONS process, but we're not sure that this would work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use scons to wrapper your configure and make script.  As long as you enumerate all your dependencies and generated targets then scons would be able to determine whether to run each of the build steps or not.  This sounds pretty complicated though. Why not convert your config and build flow to scons or write a simple makefile for this config, make dependency?  There are ways to add MD5 hashing into make ( if you're drawn to scons because of its hashing of dependencies).